# try to update mapkit

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkannotation

I want to update mapkit annotation when user press filter button 
but my map is change just one time using this method :

```
 func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

var info = MKPointAnnotation()
    info.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(26.889281, 75.836042)
    info.title = "Info1"
    mapView.addAnnotation(info)
}
```

Comment: I *think* you could only do it by removing all the annotation and add it again. That will call your delegate for view/renderer for the annotation where you can check if the filter is pressed then change the annotation.

Comment: How can I do it ? @chuthan20

Comment: How do you have it setup so far?